# How to update View inflated from XML file in a SurfaceView's onDraw(Canvas canvas) method?

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, ondraw

So I am essentially making a Pong game that has a Activity that sets its contentView() as a SurfaceView.

```
public class Pong_Activity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = Pong_Activity.class.getSimpleName();
static int screenWidth;
static int screenHeight;
public View image;
LayoutInflater inflater;
RelativeLayout mainView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    Display screen = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Rect rect_screen = new Rect();
    screen.getRectSize(rect_screen);
    screenWidth = rect_screen.width();
    screenHeight = rect_screen.height();
    Log.d(TAG, "The size of the screen is width: " + screenWidth
            + "height: " + screenHeight);
    // set Content view to surfaceView (the game panel)
    setContentView(new MainGamePanel(this));
    Log.d(TAG, "SurfaceView mainGamePanel added");
}
```

Within the SurfaceView I have overrided the onDraw() and call it continuously through an inner Thread class to make the graphics move. I know if you do not repaint the canvas the 
previous position of the graphics will be retained so I usally just call canvas.drawColor()
to get rid of that. Now I want to add in a image from my @drawables/ to place in the background of the surfaceView and refresh it when onDraw() is called, but it does not seem to be drawing the view from (background) onto the canvas.

```
public MainGamePanel(Context context ) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    // Create the thread for game loop
    thread = new gameThread(getHolder(), this);
    rectPlayer = new Player_Rect(leftX,false);
    otherPlayer = new Player_Rect(rightX,true);
    gameBall = new Ball();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    background = inflater.inflate(R.layout.basic_game_screen, null);
    setFocusable(true);
    Log.d(TAG, "mainGame Panel, thread created");

}





@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    background.draw(canvas);
    gameBall.borderCollision();
    gameBall.rectangleCollison(rectPlayer);
    gameBall.rectangleCollison(otherPlayer);
    otherPlayer.compterResponse(gameBall);
    if (gameBall.cloneBall != null) {
        gameBall.cloneBall.draw(canvas);
    }
    gameBall.draw(canvas);
    rectPlayer.draw(canvas);
    otherPlayer.draw(canvas);

}
```

This is where draw() is called, it is an inner class of MainGamepanel

```
private class gameThread extends Thread {
private boolean running;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private MainGamePanel gamePanel;
private Canvas canvas;
private static final String TAG = "gameThread";

    public gameThread(SurfaceHolder holder, MainGamePanel panel) {
        super("Gamethread");
        this.surfaceHolder = holder;
        this.gamePanel = panel;

    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long threadRunTime = 0L;
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting the game loop through game thread class.");
        while (running) {
            canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                // One accessible by one thread at a time
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    // Update the canvas by calling surface view methods.
                    this.gamePanel.onDraw(canvas);
                }

            } finally {
                // If canvas exists reupdate all the drawn objects
                // to the canvas through
                if (canvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
            threadRunTime++;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "The thread ran " + threadRunTime + "times");

    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the drawable being draw onto the canvas?

Comment: Just added it in the question, it is an inner class thread

Comment: So your background layout has your @drawables/...? Is there a reason you are doing a layout for that instead of just drawing in a bitmap?

Comment: I was originally not drawing the bitmap on the canvas with drawBitmap() because I thought inflating the picture from XML was the only was to set the width and height of the picture, (because the picture is smaller than the screen and I need to stretch it to fit it), but now I see the drawBitmap() takes a width and height parameter so that will work. @Whitney regarding drawing additional views in the surfaceView, is there any way to add a textView to it